# Shouldn't we cull welcome comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm reading through old questions and there is a distracting proliferation of "welcome comments" by Martin:

> Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify
>   your posts, have a look at the help center. Do you want to know more
>   about this site, please take the tour. –  Martin - マーチン♦ Feb 13 at 4:40

Nice sentiment, but surely this is not how comments should be used?

Should they all be flagged as obsolete?

Comment: BTW, something I find _even more_ welcoming than a canned message pointing to the tour and help: Comments about a question's content that might help a new user improve it.   And the _best_ welcome?  A good answer!

Comment: I really appreciate that you want to keep around the professional SE-style formalism. I myself were posting the "welcome"s, then read about *comment-flagging* and *too chatty is bad* horrors and told myself: "I'm [theoretically](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/), potentially screwed." However, seems like every SE has its own culture. Chem.SE users welcomed my welcoming, while I got a moderator message on ELL. Other SEs sometimes point all new users to special meta posts, sometimes don't do anything, sometimes downvote, sometimes upvote . . . Who cares?

Comment: Yes, I agree this is a style matter more than a "problem."  I do like Chem.SE, and _hope_ users feel welcome!

Comment: **NO!** These comments are what encourage new users to contribute to the site. You **may not** have them removed.\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

I'm one of the welcome-commentators. IMO they're one of the things that indicate our site's friendliness. I would by no means want their posting stopped. Comments are not first-class info, so there's really nothing wrong with this.

---

That being said, I don't really want to see a welcome comment of 2014 welcoming a user that has 2k reps now. I occasionally <sup>1</sup> take a look at our older questions to remove obsolete comments. I agree that **welcome comments older than a month are no longer needed**. You can flag them as obsolete, and our mods will hopefully remove them.

---

<sub>1: Haven't done them recently and @Martin's looking to kill me because of that.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, the year-old welcomes on Established Users are particularly bewildering ;)  Are welcome comments at least limited to truly new users, and not slapped on users that arrive with an association bonus?

Comment: @feetwet sometimes I've commented on users with Assoc. bonus too, welcoming them. Two lines of something with a link to [help] and [tour] with a smaller font don't really distract from the content, don't you think? ;) Heck, I myself sometimes need to read the other SEs' help centers to see what's on-topic and what's not. I've even grown the evil feeling that the users who actually read that stuff are going to be the least problematic.

Comment: Yes, everyone should check out what's on- and off-topic in the _help center_.  Welcomers can tell whether new users have been through the _tour_ by their Informed badge (or, association bonus, since there doesn't appear to be any Chem-unique content there).  I guess I just wanted to see if it's OK to flag the stale welcomes, and since it is I think you have a fine arrangement!

Answer (score 8):

If the welcome comments are distracting, they can be removed and probably even should. So go ahead and flag them. As a mod, these are particularly easy to deal with, too.

Thank you for having an eye open for these things.

---

For what it is worth here are some of the points that I consider when writing these comments. There is a nice script/ add-on/ extension, [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/27677), that automatically informs you how long the user is a member and how much rep s/he already gained. Occasionally I check if the *Informed* badge was already given. I post these comments to users which I think are new to the system and might need some guidance. I have addressed that on meta before: [Shouldn't we be a bit more welcoming to new askers/ posters?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/573/4945)
With that in mind, I will post the comment also to users, that have an association bonus. While I think that most users coming from a different network know about the system, I also sometimes see, that they don't know how to use the site. But I decide that on a case by case basis. Since comments are expendable I don't feel any harm doing so. I also think there is not right or wrong usage for comments (ultimately they should all be deleted).

---

When you start flagging these comments, make sure that you flag for everything that can be cleaned up, if there are multiple things to address, use a custom flag on the post itself (It is much easier to purge the comments instead of deleting all the flags).

Comment: -1 for giving away my secrets. ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)